# Estimating Fixed Effects without Random Effects

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

Probably basic question, but I'm not aure how to do it.
If one wants to estimate a multilevel model, but only with fixed effects, not random effects estimated, how one would do that?
For example, here is my model:

```
model4 <- lmer(m ~ x + (  | id) , data = data_stacked2, REML = TRUE)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `lm` instead?

Comment: `lme4` can't handle models without random effects (but the likelihoods etc. of the corresponding `lm` models are comparable). I agree with @Werner that it would be helpful if you clarified your question (e.g. gave some context about why you want to do this/what you are trying to do)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to use:

```
lmer(m ~ x + (1|id), data = data_stacked2, REML = TRUE)
```

To be more specific, the above model has fixed (`x`) and random effects (`id`). If you don't need to estimate random effects, just use `lm(m ~ x, data)` instead.

But If you're trying to run a model with random slopes and a fixed intercept, you might want to try the formula

```
lmer(m ~ 1 + (0 + x|id), data = data_stacked2, REML = TRUE)
```

Please clarify your question.

Comment: If one would want to estimate a fixed-intercept only model (i.e. without random slopes), with m as a dv and x as the iv, how one would do so?

Comment: Linear model: lm(m ~ x, data)

Comment: perfect, thank you!